# .htaccess redirect to http if url contains string

Tags: php, .htaccess, redirect

I'm trying to config my htaccess so that if a URL in my website contains 
Buy,Rent,Make-offer,Sold to redirect https requests to http

This is what I've tried with no luck

```
# Redirect other HTTPS requests to plain HTTP
RewriteCond %{HTTPS} on
RewriteRule ^(buy|rent|sold|make-offer)$ http://%{HTTP_HOST}%{REQUEST_URI} [R=301,L,QSA]
```

Can someone help me?

Comment: Useful information for this question is: What is the exact url you are testing this with? That is: Copy and paste the url here, and for privacy's sake replace the domain name with "example.com".

Comment: This will only and exactly match `/buy`, `/rent`, `/sold` and `/make-offer`. Is that what you really want to do?

Comment: So this is a sample url https://example.com/buy/1241-187-collins-st-melbourne-vic-3000

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Your match pattern contains beginning and end of string anchors (`^` and`$`) so will only match URLs which are `//host/buy` etc.  If you want beginning with then drop the `$` and if you want contains, then drop both.  If you want "which contains the word buy ..." then use

```
  RewriteRule \b(buy|rent|sold|make-offer)\b http://%{HTTP_HOST}%{REQUEST_URI} [R=301,L,QSA]
```

etc.  Hope this helps.

Comment: This is a sample URL https://example.com/buy/1241-187-collins-st-melbourne-vic-3000 I have used your solution but it doesn't goto http

Comment: The QSA flag is not required here, but otherwise this should work. Have you enabled the RewriteEngine with `RewriteEngine on`? Is your .htaccess file in your document root?

Comment: this is what i have  RewriteEngine On

    RewriteCond %{REQUEST_FILENAME} !-d
    RewriteCond %{REQUEST_FILENAME} !-f
    RewriteRule ^ index.php [L]
    RewriteRule \b(buy|rent|sold|make-offer)\b http://%{HTTP_HOST}%{REQUEST_URI} [R=301,L,QSA]

Comment: This is what I get when I switch the rules The page isn't redirecting properly

Firefox has detected that the server is redirecting the request for this address in a way that will never complete.

    This problem can sometimes be caused by disabling or refusing to accept cookies.

Comment: got it to work by changing the rules around thanks for the input